# Disable dragging Google Maps while in drawing mode

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a page where people can draw a line over a fixed region so I want to stop the map from being panned,dragged, zoomed or moved in anyway. I've set everything I can find to false and it works fine in normal viewing mode, but when the user starts drawing using the Drawing Manager the scroll-to-zoom comes back as well as the click-to-drag. My first thought is that this is a bug/oversight in Google's code, but I'm hoping someone has a work around.

```
var myOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25,177.5),
  zoom: 3,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
  streetViewControl : false,
  zoomControl: false,
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  draggable: false,
  keyboardShortcuts : false,
  navigationControl : false,
  scaleControl : false,
  scrollwheel : false,
  streetViewControl : false
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

*update: This is the Drawing Manager code*

```
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE]
      },
      polylineOptions: {
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeColor: '#ee9900',
        clickable: false,
        zIndex: 1,
        editable: true
      }
    });
drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

Comment: How does the drawing manager access google maps?

Comment: Added the code above. As far as I can see there is nothing strange about it. I copied it straight of Google's documentation page. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawingmanager_options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add this to the Google Maps API issue tracker

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

This indeed does look like an issue with API - basically a usecase that Google didnt consider.

BUT, I highly recommend you setup a page as a demo, and include the link in the issue report.

I'm taking you at your word that this is happening, but an issue carries x100 times the weight, if there is a very easy way for others to verify (ie see it with their own eyes).

(yes, people can try and take your code to replicate it, but 1. its a lot of work, and 2. there is a high chance of inadvertantly doing something differnt and thereby side-stepping the issue)

Comment: I've added it to their tracker and added an example page http://dl.dropbox.com/u/474350/tmp/draggablemaptest.html

Comment: Accepted as a bug, if no-one comes up with a work around you get the points.  http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4012